# How can I concatenate and move multiple cell values depending on some conditions by using Google app script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to rearrange some questions stored in a Google Sheets document. The questions are split across multiple cells in columns A and B to H. Column A contains the first part of each question. Columns B to H mistakenly contain additional parts of the questions, mainly the options related to each question. Now, some questions' last parts are mistakenly stored in cells within columns B to H, causing the questions to be split across multiple cells. I need to identify and concatenate all parts of each question, starting from column A until we encounter the first occurrence of a cell starting with "a) " in columns B to H. Once I find the start of the option (identified by "a) "), I need to concatenate all parts as the question and store it in the corresponding cell in column A. I should then clear all the cells before the one containing "a) ".

I am using Google Apps Script to iterate through each row in column A. For each row, I check if the next row in column A is empty, indicating the start of a new question. If the next row in column A is empty, it concatenates all non-empty cells in columns B to H until a cell starting with "a) ". Once it finds such a cell, it concatenates all parts of the question and store it in in column A and clear the cells in columns B to H that contained the additional parts of the question. then, I tried to repeat this process for each question in column A until the last row but the script is not correctly identifying the start of options (identified by "a) ") in columns B to H. It is also be moving some cell's data unnecessarily.

Here is the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12xIwwecDIAp5iSITNmrenmB4eCzWpLp31eQKrmqV2oU/edit?usp=sharing)
A1:A is containing the first part of a lot of questions and B1:H is containing Options. But unfortunately some question's last part gets mixed in B1:H. Please revise me the script to check A1:A one by one. If SELECTED_CELL + 1 is empty then it is the first part of a question. now we will find if anything of the cell is left apart. We will keep the value in a variable (WHOLE_QUESTION) and search for the cell containing "ক)" in B[SELECTED_CELL]:H. Untill we get the cell containing "ক)" every cell will be concatenated into WHOLE_QUESTION with " " and get cleaned. If we find the cell containing "ক)" then current task is almost complete. Just put the concatenated whole question in SELECTED_CELL. and find the next SELECTED_CELL which next cell (SELECTED_CELL + 1) is empty and repeat. Like for the question in A6, B8 is containing "a) " [a) ৩৬০০ টাকা] every non empty cell before B8 should be concatenated with A6. For the question in A20, B25 is containing "a) ". So every non-empty cell before B25 should go to A20. I have included it in the sheet.

The script I am trying to use:

```
function rearrangeQuestions() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Loop through each row in column A
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange("A" + i);
    var cellValue = cell.getValue().toString();

    // Check if the cell in the next row is empty
    if (sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)).isBlank()) {
      var wholeQuestion = cellValue; // Initialize the whole question

      // Loop through columns B to H to concatenate parts of the question
      for (var j = 2; j <= 8; j++) {
        var option = sheet.getRange(i, j).getValue().toString();
        wholeQuestion += (option !== "" ? " " + option : ""); // Concatenate if the cell is not empty
        sheet.getRange(i, j).clearContent(); // Clear the current cell

        // Check if the option starts with "a) "
        if (option.trim().startsWith("a) ")) {
          // Set the concatenated whole question in the selected cell (column A)
          cell.setValue(wholeQuestion.trim());
          break; // Exit loop if "a) " is found
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot, tried to take the help of ChatGPT too but no luck. Please help me.

Comment: You want to concatenation a), b), c) and d) which may be on multiple lines?

Comment: @TheWizEd I think that is essentiallly true but in any given question some of the characters found in column B belong to the question in column A if you have not yet seen an a) in the sequence of characters and most of the characters are Chinese I believe.

Comment: I believe that lines that only have content in column A can be used as question delimiters.

Comment: I will offer no other comments since the OP and I had an unpleasant exchange earlier and I am afraid my assistance is not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but I'll give it a try.

I believe what you want is anything following text in column A that is blank in column A and not starting with "a)" in column B to be concatenated to that text.

Here is an example using a copy of your spreadsheet.  I place the results in Sheet2 so you can check it is doing what you want.

```
function rearrangeQuestions() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    let text = ";"
    values.forEach( (row,index) => {
      if( index === 0 ) return
        if( row[0] !== "" ) {
          currentRow = index;  //  save the row of the
          text = row[0];
        }
        else if ( row[1].startsWith("a)") ) {
          values[currentRow][0] = text;
          text = "";
        }
        else {
          text = text.concat(" ",row[1]);
          row[1] = "";
        }
      }
    )
    sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet2");  // coment out to overwrite Sheet1
    sheet.getRange(1,1,values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [SpreadsheetApp.getctiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [String.startsWith()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: startsWith("a)"), ("b)") ... works for me just fine. Thanks a huge lot.